# Pathfinder not acting correctly

Tags: c#, ai

I've taken the A* Algorithm from this example [XNA Pathfinder Example](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/pathfinding) so that it will be able to plot a path for a moving goal.

The issue I'm having is that it will go in the right general direction but it will keep going back and forth in a line. I've changed the method so that it calculates a new path every half a second, clear out the previous points from the list and adds the new points to and from what I have debugged I can't find any issue with the points being added to the queue, to be honest I don't have the foggiest idea what is going wrong :/

This is the field where the waypoints are being held for the character

```
private Queue<Vector2> waypoints = new Queue<Vector2>();
```

This section is in the update loop and deals with the plotting a new path and laying out the new one onto the list mentioned above.

```
            timer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;

            if (timer.Seconds >= 0.5)
            {
                timer = TimeSpan.Zero;
                pathFinder.NewPath(position);
            }

            if (pathFinder.SearchStatus == SearchStatus.PathFound)
            {
                waypoints.Clear();
                foreach (Point point in pathFinder.FinalPath())
                {
                    Waypoints.Enqueue(level.MapToWorld(point, true));
                }
                moving = true;
            }
```

This section is where the waypoints are either taken off or used to set the new position of the character.

```
                if (moving)
                {
                    // If we have any waypoints, the first one on the list is where 
                    // we want to go
                    if (waypoints.Count >= 1)
                    {
                        destination = waypoints.Peek();
                    }

                    // If we’re at the destination and there is at least one waypoint in 
                    // the list, get rid of the first one since we’re there now
                    if (AtDestination && waypoints.Count >= 1)
                    {
                        waypoints.Dequeue();
                    }
                    if (!AtDestination)
                    {
                        direction = -(position - destination);
                        //This scales the vector to 1, we'll use move Speed and elapsed Time 
                        //to find the how far the tank moves
                        direction.Normalize();
                        position = position + (direction * MoveSpeed * elapsedTime);
                    }                  
                 }
```

Comment: Is it possible that when it recalculates the next best position, it thinks going "forth" is a good idea so it goes that way. Then, when it checks a half second later, it thinks "back" is a good idea and goes back that way since you're erasing the old path?

Comment: "it calculates a new path every half a second", you shouldn't need to do that unless the environment is changing. A simple debug check would be to draw the waypoints and/or lines between the waypoints, this would allow you to visually see what is happening. As for your code, I don't see anything obvious.

Comment: @Dirckir, that is probably it

Comment: @John I'm recalculating the path every half a second due to the end point is constantly moving, also good idea I will draw out the waypoints

Comment: If Drackir's answer does happen to be correct, maybe you can weight the existing path more than picking a new path.

Comment: @John McD His answer is correct, also mind explaining to me by weighting the path more, keeping in mind the end point is constantly moving.

Comment: Well... In a typical A* algorithm, you assign a cost of a tile based on the "length" of the path taken to get to the tile in question PLUS the Hamiltonian distance to the target. This cost could be altered (much like diagonals having a higher cost) to have a lower cost if the tile is on the existing route. That way, it will prefer the existing route, but won't be restricted to it.

Comment: Hmm looked at the example I picked up and A* algoritm in that is calculated soley based off the heuristic value, so I need to heavily modify that bad boy

Comment: An additional note: The A* method I used just approximated the distance to the destination using the Hamiltonian distance. If the algorithm you are using has a different or better way to do this, I would leave that part alone. 
So in summary, instead of adding 1 to the path's cost for moving from tile to tile, do something like multiply all values by 10 (or use floats), so add 10 the path's cost for moving from tile to tile. Something like 13 is common if the path is diagonal, and I'd do something like 7 if the destination tile is on the old path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* I happened upon this because "Community" bumped it and I see that my comment was helpful so I figured I'd post it as an answer.

---

Is it possible that when it recalculates the next best position, it thinks going "forth" is a good idea so it goes that way. Then, when it checks a half second later, it thinks "back" is a good idea and goes back that way since you're erasing the old path?

As John McDonald described in the comments, to fix this you could weight the points already on the path so that it's more likely to follow the previous path but isn't necessarily stuck to it.

Comment: Yeah that was pretty much it thanks for the info though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your character should check for a new destination only when it has reached the current destination. 
At this point if your target has changed you should recalc the path.

I'm afraid with the AtDestination calcs. I'd like to see how you determine it.